# ol3: how to add coordinate programmatically while drawing

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to add coordinates programmatically to the geometry while drawing.

I can access the geometry in the geometryfunction and this works, but when i move the cursor the geometry resets to the old one without the coordinate inserted in the geometryFunction.

I've tried it also with the drawinteractions features collection but gives the same result.

Thank you!

EDIT:
it works with the geometryfunction, but it's necessary to move to cursor after the insert to see the changes. It's possible to see it immediate?

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
        layer: 'sat'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
var source = new ol.source.Vector();
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  name: 'layer'
});
map.addLayer(layer);
var drawFeaturesCollection = new ol.Collection();
var drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  'type': 'Polygon',
  'source': source,
  'geometryFunction': onDrawPolygon,
  'features': drawFeaturesCollection
});
drawInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
  currentDrawingGeom = undefined;
});
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
var currentDrawingGeom;
var addCoordinate = false;
var coord1 = [2690583.395638204, 585201.8885513092];
var coord2 = [2270583.395638204, 543201.8885513092];
var added1 = false;

function onDrawPolygon(coordinates, geometry) {
  if (geometry) {
    if (addCoordinate) {
      coordinates[0].splice(coordinates.length - 2, 0, added1 ? coord2 : coord1);
      added1 = !added1;
      addCoordinate = false;
    }
    geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);
  } else {
    geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates);
  }
  currentDrawingGeom = geometry;
  return geometry;
}

function addCoord() {
  addCoordinate = true;
}

function clearLayer() {
  layer.getSource().clear();
}

function addCoordColl() {
  var coords = currentDrawingGeom.getCoordinates();
  coords[0].splice(coords.length - 2, 0, coord1);
  currentDrawingGeom.setCoordinates(coords);
}
```

here a codepen example:
    http://codepen.io/lukasoberhoeller/pen/EyamBr

thank you!

Comment: thanks for your response! i've updated the question

Comment: Try some keyboard shortcut and see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3LS1wU1Xjm3jfIShF0Ny?p=preview).

Comment: thanks. it works with the delete, for that you can use a ol3 function "removeLastPoint", for adding a new one isn't a function that updates the current drawing geometry.